# SMS Broadcast Priority

Tags: android, sms, broadcast

In my Application , iam Using a Broadcast Receiver to Intercept SMS , android:priority:100 , Priority is Set to 100 , Everything is Working Fine Exepted when Using the Application 'Go SMS' , Go SMS Intercept SMS Message Before other Application , it is Related to the Broadcast Priority , Package Name , Installation Date ? ,

Thanks .

Comment: yep, android:priority is the one. must be an integer. the higher the number, the higher the priority

Answer (score 1):

> Go SMS Intercept SMS Message Before other Application , it is Related to the Broadcast Priority

It is related to the `android:priority` of the `<intent-filter>` for the `BroadcastReceiver`. Last I checked, Go SMS has theirs set to the highest possible value.

Comment: so what is the Solution ? what is the Highest Integer ?

Comment: Ok so the Higher Integer 2147483647 i have found , its work , but Broadcast is not aborted , Go SMS Receive the Broadcast and my App Too